# Changing Exchange primary email address with respect to BlackBerry Server

Tags: exchange, blackberry, bes

What impact (if any) does changing a primary email address in Exchange have on BlackBerries that are activated on that server?

For example, say I have a primary email address of user@xyz.com and I have a BlackBerry that has been activated with that address. Now say that primary address changes to user@abc.com? Will I need to wipe and re-activate my BlackBerry or will it be a seamless change?

Now, what happens if the company no longer has the xyz.com (former primary) domain but adds the def.com domain and makes that the primary?

Sorry if my question isn't clear. Let me know if there are any questions and I'll clarify. For what it's worth, a 3rd party does our Exchange/BES hosting and I asked them this same question. They said it shouldn't have any impact but that was a "best guess".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, It shouldn't matter, as its not based on the email address, but the device PIN. Basically, the device is registered to the BES via its PIN, and tied to the user account, you can change their email address and mail will still be delivered.

Answer (score 1):

Since the BES associates with the users exchange account and not the email address.  I don't see how this could have any impact on them.  Email going into their mailbox will continue to be sync'd.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the etp.dat message which the phone/blackberry interface (BBI) sends to your mailbox is found then it shouldnt matter. When an activation password is set the BES server will just sit there monitoring the users mailbox for the incomming etp.dat.

As long as your spam filter or users outlook doesnt fiddle with that email you'll be fine